# webpack-stream, ошибки компиляции

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, webpack2, webpack-stream

Используется `webpack-stream`, задача вынесена в отдельный модуль

```
module.exports = function(options) {

    return function(callback) {
        let buildReady = false;

        function done(err, stats) {
            buildReady = true;

            if (err) {
                return;
            }
            $.util.log('[webpack] Completed\n' + stats.toString({
                assets: true,
                chunks: false,
                chunkModules: false,
                colors: true,
                hash: false,
                timings: false,
                version: true
            }));

        }
        return gulp.src(options.path.src.js)
            .pipe($.plumber({
                errorHandler: $.notify.onError(err => ({
                    title: 'Webpack',
                    message: err.message
                }))
            }))
            .pipe(named())
            .pipe(webpack(webpackConfig, core , done ))
            .pipe($.debug({title: 'dest'})) // при ошибке компиляции сюда поток уже не передается.
            .pipe(gulp.dest(options.path.build.jsDir));
    };

};
```

Есть одна проблема, если произошла ошибка, задача не падает и продолжает выпонение, только вот `webpack-sream` перестает испускать поток и соответственно в `gulp.dest` ничего не приходит. Используется вебпаковский вотчер. С галповским работает.